# 404 error in Spring Maven project

Tags: spring, maven, http-status-code-404

[image]I am new to Spring and trying to develop one small application using spring annotation with Maven. But I am getting **"The requested resource is not available."**I can understand that server is not able to locate the requested resource. But I am not able to resolve it, So please help me on this.

Below are my project structure and code:-

```
SpringRootConfig.java
package com.capp.config;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
@Configurable
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.capp"})
public class SpringRootConfig {


}

    package com.capp.config;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Configurable
    @ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.capp"})
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {


        }

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

            InternalResourceViewResolver vr =new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            vr.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            vr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
            vr.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return vr;
        }
    }
    ContactAppDispatcherServletIntializer.java
    package com.capp.config;

    import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;

    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

    public class ContactAppDispatcherServletIntializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] {SpringRootConfig.class};
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new Class[] {SpringRootConfig.class};
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new String[] {"/"};
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStartup(servletContext);
        }




    }
TestController.java    
package com.capp.controller;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    @Controller
    public class TestController {

        @RequestMapping(value="/test/hello")
        public String helloWorld() {

            return "hello";
        }

    }
```

When i am runing the application with http://localhost:8080/SpringContactApp/test/hello not able to find the hello.jsp which is under WEB-INF folder.[image]

Comment: What is below your WEB-INF folder?

Comment: Hi Lars, Below WEB-INF/view/hello.jsp,Add new image also for that

Comment: Hmm, what's in the stack trace then?

Comment: Noting is printing in the console of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the JSP is directly under the WEB-INF folder. If this is the case, create a subdirectory 'view' and move the JSP there.

In the view resolver, you set the prefix to "/WEB-INF/view/", your view resources must be in that location.

Comment: Hi Lars,I have the same project structure as mentioned by you but it is still not able to find the jsp..

Comment: Hi All, Able to find out the reason, My all jar files are available at the build path and not in the lib folder. So move all the jars to lib folder and it works fine.